# On .click() event to .get() page and replace .html() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have `div class="contentBlock"` which is treated as the container for updating

```
 <div class="contentBlock"></div>
```

I have a script that I wrote that doesnt work :c

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.postLink').on('click', function () {
    $.get("page.php", function (data) {
      $(".contentBlock").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

I have a anchor html

```
<div class="box"> 
  <a class="postLink" "href="#">
    <h1 title="Light me up"></h1>
    <div class="innerbox">
      <figure><img src="http://cpsr-rspc.hc-sc.gc.ca/PR-RP/servlet/ShowImage?photoId=1789" /></figure>
      <ul class="categorySelect">
        <li class="print"></li>
        <li class="video"></li>
        <li class="web"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </a> 
</div>
```

The `page.php` is just an `img` tag amd some lorem.

I've never worked with `.get()` I'm sure I'm using it incorrectly. Additionally, where would I add a transition for a loading .gif and a fadein when loaded?

Comment: I may be wrong but i was looking at something ilke this earlier, I think there was a .load somewhere! I will see if i can find it!

Comment: The code seems to be correct. However, you may use `load()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: Have a look at this page, i believe its what you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101770/load-content-of-a-div-on-another-page

Comment: The code should work, however your anchor tag has an extra `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a class="postLink" "href="#">
```

Should be

```
<a class="postLink" href="#">
```

You had an extra quote.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".postLink").on('click', function () {
     // load in animation.gif here
     $(".contentBlock").load("page.php", function() {
         // end loading animation now
     });
  });
});
```

Using a load in jQuery is meant for exactly this purpose.

Here's the jQuery doc for load: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery is there a better way to write this code so i can use load in and out for transitional purposes

Comment: I agree that `load` is cleaner here, but if it didn't work with `$.get`, why would it work with `load`? I think something else is going on...

Comment: The main question already has the solution for that, the anchor tag has an extra quote.

Comment: my god thank you for that retarded quote typo.. it created this crazyyyy error and I was dumbfounded as to why it was happening and it just randomly happened so I thought it was totally the script hahah.