# load div content from external file

Tags: php, jquery, load, external

I've tried several options to try and load the content from a div on one page with id="container" into a div on a different html page id="landing".

I used the answer here and also lots of variations of it
[Load content of a div on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101770/load-content-of-a-div-on-another-page)

I've run a test and Jquery is being loaded.

The test files are here http://www.salcombeyurts.co.uk/test/landing.html

My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#landing').load('source.html #container');
</script>
```

This will eventually end up on a PHP page. Part of a Joomla site.

Comment: What happens when you remove the space between `source.html` and `#container`?  Also, you need to enclose your `load` function within a `$(document).ready`.

Comment: In your "Developer Tools" have you verified that `source.html` is being requested correctly?

Comment: I see you are using jQuery load function, even I used it, it works fine. So where you have been stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You run the script before the `#landing` div is defined.

Run your code after the DOM ready event

```
$(function(){
    $('#landing').load('source.html #container');
});
```

Comment: In my opinion it's pretty obvious that this is the problem, not the space between the container and file name, which according to the docs is just as it should be. +1 !

Comment: That has answered it. Classic CSS developer error, running the script before the DOM.

Comment: Can this be done with a generated URL. I.e. without an extension?

Comment: @DanielMichaelAshton, ofcourse. If the server responds correctly to the generated URL then you have no problem..

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli, I've implemented this here http://www.salcombeyurts.co.uk/stage/availability.html, it works on my test page here http://www.salcombeyurts.com/test/landing.html outside the CMS http://www.salcombeyurts.com/test/landing.html, but as you can see when I try the same thing on the full site the content isn't loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the suggestion you got was to do an AJAX request and load the entire page into the #container div on the current page, which is not a bad idea. What you seem to be trying to do, on the other hand, is load the page and then get the content of a div inside that page and put it in a container div on the current page, which is overly complicated and a bad solution to what ever the problem is.

Here is my solution none the less

```
$(function() {
    $.get('page with the div you want', function(data) {
        var content = $(data); //turn the page into a jquery object
        var div = content.find('#div'); // this is the div you want the content from
        $('#container').html(div.html()); // this will set the content of the current div
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is I have availability tables on pages like this http://www.salcombeyurts.co.uk/stage/index.php/yurt1 that I want to feed onto a summary page that will display 4 different tables from 4 different URL's. The problem comes from the fact the component I have used does not come with a joomla module option or shortcode to embed into articles. You can only directly link to the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would move your script to the bottom of the page and replace it like so.

Original:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#landing').load('source.html #container');
</script>
```

New:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#landing').load('source.html #container');
});
</script>
```

<strike>Note the space removal between `source.html` and `#container.`</strike>

Comment: note that according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) that space should actually be there ?

Comment: Interesting... thanks for the note.  I just assumed you would design the URL as you would for a link - in which case, you wouldn't have the space there.

Comment: Yes, if it's the hash part of the url, there would'nt be a space there. For filtering the returned content based on a selector, the space should be there.