# Pass div and value from one page to another

Tags: javascript

I have assigned an id of the user's name to each div generated by loop. This is fine. Each div/button has the username as its identity. However, using the examples here [Load content of a div on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101770/load-content-of-a-div-on-another-page) and in other posts I am trying to send that div and its contents to another page and also pass the name value with it. My attempt is not working although the alert is alerting the name. Am I correctly passing the value? How can I recreate the div on the next page? Finally, is this even the correct approach because eventually I want to attach a table to the person. Long-winded enough?

```
     identity = results.rows.item(i).username;
        userDiv.id = identity;
        console.log(identity);
        (function (identity) {
            userDiv.addEventListener("click",

            function () {
                window.open("whatever.html");
                $('#singleUser').load('index.html #userDiv');
                //var singleUser = document.getElementById("singleUser");
                //singleUser.appendChild(userDiv);
                alert(identity);
                console.log(identity);
            }, false);
        })(identity);
```

Comment: I would say, blindly since we don't have much in the way of examples, that your approach is probably wrong. You will need to either have the framework already built in HTML and pass values through query strings or cookies, or load content from another file (text file or otherwise) from the server using AJAX methods. Either way, you'll need a pre-detirmined framework and pass values to it using query strings or Cookies.

Comment: Hi Jimmmy thanks for the reply it saved me from getting another tumbleweed badge! I think you may be right. Anyway, back to the drawing board.

Comment: No problem, sometimes folks can be harsh on here :)