# Load specific data from external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Given Script load data from specific div of external source on click. It load all data form a div of external source. But now trying to load only specific things I want. Like load only image, then title, post Label, date and comments only, not text summery, in same order.

**Script:**

```
$(function() {
    var page = null;
    var counter = 0;

    function getNext() {
    // Grab the next element from the array of date-outer divs and copy it to the .content div
        if (counter >= page.length)
            return;
        var elm = $(page[counter]).clone();
        elm.find('script').remove(); // Remove script tags in the div
        elm.appendTo('#load-here');
        counter++;
    }

    $('button.btn').click(function(e) {
        if (page === null) {
            page = false; // Prevents the request from being made twice
            $.get('http://test-html-site.blogspot.com/search/label/', function(data) {
                page = $(data).find('.date-outer');
                getNext();
            });
        } else if (page !== false) {
            getNext();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<button class='btn'/>
<div id="load-here"></div> <!-- Load Here -->

</body>
```

**HTML Structure of external site:** 

Given script load `.date-outer` per click.

```
<body>
<div class="blog-posts hfeed"> 

<div class="date-outer">
Contecnt 1: Title, img, comments, text </div>

<div class="date-outer">
Contecnt 2: Title, img, comments, text </div>

<div class="date-outer">
Contecnt 3: Title, img, comments, text </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Example External site [link](http://test-html-site.blogspot.com/search/label/)

Single [Content structure](http://test-html-site.blogspot.com/2014/08/user-friendly-layout.html).

My question is how to load only specific data, like image, then title, Post Labels, date and comments only, not text summery, in same order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet for selecting particular content from external source

```
$('#Destination-image1-Id').load('XXX.html #image1');
```

Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101874/2632619

Comment: Not like this, click function required, please see here: http://test-html-site.blogspot.com/ when click the "Click here" Button it show all content, but i want to load specific data.