# Regarding AngularJs ng-if and html5

Tags: angularjs, html

As I am new to `angularjs` , I am using `ng-if` in `page1.html` , and it is working fine , means if i click `checkbox` it is showing the `div` element and if i uncheck the check box it is hiding.

My question is , if i click `check box` the `div` element associated with `ng-if` has to be show in `page1.html` and as well as in `page2.html.` 
Can any one help me , in angular way.

Comment: can you show some code, and describe how page1 and page2 are being shown

Comment: Or sir can we do it in another way like , from one page send the div element to another page in angular way.

Comment: create a fiddle or plunkr to show what do you want

Comment: [http://plnkr.co/edit/vyrb0xuvlzvffwnzwqcW?p=catalogue]

Comment: Please check [http://plnkr.co/edit/vyrb0xuvlzvffwnzwqcW?p=catalogue] this link

Comment: and please check readme file.

Comment: some thing like this ""$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');""

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101770/load-content-of-a-div-on-another-page)