# Wordpress: display a certain <div> into another page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm working on this [website](http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen/)  and i need to display the `<div>` where the **table** is into another page, so i just have to edit one time the table for both pages.

I need to display this `<div id="table" class="dslc-modules-section " style="padding-bottom:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-left:2.5%;padding-right:2.5%;">`  **without** using `<iframe>` into another page.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advice

**EDIT**: using the jquery load `.load()` now i am able to display the same table that i have in this [page](http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen/)  also into this [page](http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen-en/). But i  still have a problem: the table javascript in the second page does not works. The table should be animated as [here](http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen/) bus seems like not loaded. How come?

I used this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#table_en').load('http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen/ #table');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please refer this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101770/load-content-of-a-div-on-another-page

Comment: @purvik7373 i did, and now i'm able to load the div into another page, but the other javascript code looks like not well loaded. Can you please read my first post? I just edited it.