# Fetching random articles from wikipedia

Tags: php, html, wikipedia

Hi i am working on a site which fetches random articles from Wikipedia and displays them on my site.
The problem is i have no idea how to retrieve those articles. Documentation is also of no help.
Can someone advice me how to approach it?
Can we use api's? 
I am using PHP+HTML.

Comment: Welcome. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what is in scope at Stack Overflow.

Comment: The link to a random article on Wikipedia is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random`. You could just make an AJAX call to that page, and then place the contents of the return data's `<body>` tag where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Very recently there's been a new [API endpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/?doc#!/Page_content/get_page_random_format) released.

It gives you the random article in a requested format, which could be just a title, html, summary, mobile-sections or mobile-sections-lead (special formats optimised for use in mobile apps). Also it's possible to get a set of articles related to a random article.

Also this is a 'smart random' - it filters out articles without content, special pages etc, so you are a bit more certain to get a good random article using this API endpoint, then a special page.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random
It will show you a random article. You can try to in include it on your site with php or as iframe.

Comment: What i want is that the whole article is displayed "as is" on my site.

Comment: You mean the article without wikipedias menu-bar? Then you could try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101770/load-content-of-a-div-on-another-page

Comment: Thanks but that is implemented through JQuery isn't there any PHP workaround?

Comment: I can't imagine how to do this with php but you could try to play around with the `include("")` method.

Comment: Okay no problem mate.. Hopefully someone else finds a workaround